# Different combobox items selected should display different text

Tags: c#, combobox, textbox

I got a question again. I'm writing a program which lists all my to do's. This program contains 2 tabs. In tab1 I can create a new To Do and in tab2 I can select a To Do and it should display all the details I typed in in tab1. For example:

"New To Do: Name = Test, comments = this is just a test"

When I switch to tab2 now and select "Test" in combobox, it should display the comment "this is just a test".

I tried it for myself but I'm a beginner and so my code is not really clever:

```
private void combox_Name2_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (combox_Name2.SelectedIndex > -1)
    {
        lbl_ShowComment.Text = txt_Comment.Text;
    }
}
```

This (logically) just display the comment which now is in the textbox from tab1. But if I got more items in combobox, it should display the correct comment. Has someone a hint for me?

Cheers

Comment: So what currently happens? error? wrong text displayed?

Comment: It just display the comment which is in the textbox from tab1. If I got more items in combobox, it should display the correct one

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a large part of your application, you need to find a way to store the 'todos' that you create in the first tab. I would recommend a database (try `MySQL`, cos its the free-est). Or if you don't want to install a database, you can use a `DataTable` which can save to and load from an XML file of your choosing.

Have a look into tutorials on these two things. Then once you know how to use them, selecting data from them will be a `cake-walk`.